# Visual Studio Code ModuleNotFoundError: No Module Named Seaborn

Tags: anaconda, seaborn, conda

can you help me out with this
I'm trying to `import seaborn as sns`

but on my screen, it just showed

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn'

I tried to uninstall then re-installed seaborn on anaconda so many times but it doesn't work

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Please, check if, in VSCode, you are using the Python environment in which you installed Seaborn. Refer to [this post](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments). You may be using a Python environment that is not from Anaconda.

You may also try to install the package via VSCode, using the normal conda or pip commands as they tell [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/installing.html). In this case, the package is installed in the environment in use.